Angular V17 to V18 update in project
Does anyone know how to update a project from Angular v17 to v18 because I can't find any documentation related to version updates on angular.dev. If someone knows how to do that - can you please guide me? Thanks in advance!

Maybe the best approach can be creating a new angular v18 project, and transfer its components, pipes, services.

how about running ng update? did you try?

They have the official guide on their website
https://angular.dev/update-guide

No idea why this was downvoted, this should be the only accepted answer. Angular made it easy for anyone to update from/to a specific version, just follow this guide.

Yesh I got it. Thank you.
